# centos 7 mount with atime enabled

Tags: linux, mount

I am unable to mount an ext4 partition with atime enabled.

/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/datacore type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)

I am able to mount with noatime or realtime.   Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: No error message.   unfortunately

Comment: So what is the symptom? "unable to mount" does not say much.

Comment: I am not able to set the atime option.  When I specify atime it just seems to ignore the option.  All other options seem to work.  (noatime, realtime)   Can you mount centos 7 with this option enabled?   Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: So you are doing `mount -o atime /dev/sdX /mount`? The mount(1) man page says that `atime` sets the policy to the kernel default (which currently is `relatime` I believe). If you want to set it to the original policy of updating the atime any time the file is touched in any way, you have to say `-o strictatime`. Can you try that? BTW, why is `relatime` not sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: thanks Nick! that worked.  funny thing is that it still does not display this option /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/datacore type ext4 (rw,data=ordered).  I am trying to move files off my most expensive and fastest storage that are not being used.